# Selinux audit log - translate

Tags: linux, centos, selinux

I would like to centralize all audit logs trough syslog in one server. I did setup it up and install `setroubleshoot-server`.

In order to translate `audit.log` into human language, I would like to use `sealert`.

Command : `sealert -a /var/log/audit/audit.log`

But I got error `[Errno 22] Invalid argument`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setroubleshoot-server` and `sealert` are for investigating SELinux denials.  `/var/log/audit/audit.log` is generated by `auditd` and can be parsed using `ausearch` and `aureport`.

Check the relevant manpages:  [auditd](https://linux.die.net/man/8/auditd), [ausearch](https://linux.die.net/man/8/ausearch), [aureport](https://linux.die.net/man/8/aureport).

Comment: If this helped, please select it as an accepted answer to help others in the future.